# Finding out if a form element is of type select using its name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST" ACTION="survey.php">
    <p>q2: Who is your best best friend?</P>
    <select name='q2' id='q21'>
        <option value='0'>Select a Name</option>
        <option value='2001'>Ahmed Ebaid</option>
        <option value='2002'>Jaida ElTayeby</option>
        <option value='2003'>Farida Ebaid</option>
        <option value='2005'>Kenny Andersen</option>
        <option value='2006'>Nadine Saad</option>
        <option value='2007'>AbdElHai Ebaid</option>
        <option value='2008'>Salwa AbdElAal</option>
    </select>
    <select name='q2' id='q22'>
        <option value='0'>Select a Name</option>
        <option value='2001'>Ahmed Ebaid</option>
        <option value='2002'>Jaida ElTayeby</option>
        <option value='2003'>Farida Ebaid</option>
        <option value='2005'>Kenny Andersen</option>
        <option value='2006'>Nadine Saad</option>
        <option value='2007'>AbdElHai Ebaid</option>
        <option value='2008'>Salwa AbdElAal</option>
    </select>
    <P>q3: How do you rate AbdElHai Ebaid?</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q3' value='1' >1</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q3' value='2' >2</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q3' value='3' >3</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q3' value='4' >4</P>
    <P>
        <INPUT TYPE='Radio' Name='q3' value='5' >5</P><span style='color:red' id='radio_error'></span>
    <p>q4: Who is your best best friend?</P>
    <select name='q4' id='q41'>
        <option value='0'>Select a Name</option>
        <option value='2001'>Ahmed Ebaid</option>
        <option value='2002'>Jaida ElTayeby</option>
        <option value='2003'>Farida Ebaid</option>
        <option value='2005'>Kenny Andersen</option>
        <option value='2006'>Nadine Saad</option>
        <option value='2007'>AbdElHai Ebaid</option>
        <option value='2008'>Salwa AbdElAal</option>
    </select>
    <select name='q4' id='q42'>
        <option value='0'>Select a Name</option>
        <option value='2001'>Ahmed Ebaid</option>
        <option value='2002'>Jaida ElTayeby</option>
        <option value='2003'>Farida Ebaid</option>
        <option value='2005'>Kenny Andersen</option>
        <option value='2006'>Nadine Saad</option>
        <option value='2007'>AbdElHai Ebaid</option>
        <option value='2008'>Salwa AbdElAal</option>
    </select>

    <p>
        <INPUT TYPE="Submit" Name="Submit1" VALUE="Click here to vote">
    </P>
</form>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
if ($('#'+qNum+'').is(':radio')) {
                if (($('input[name='+qNum+']:checked').length == 0) ){
                    alert("No Selection is made for "+ qNum);
                    return false;
                }
            }
    else if ($('[name="' + qNum + '"]').is(':radio')) {
                    var j = 1;
                    var nominatefriend = qNum+j;
                                    alert (nominatefriend);
    }
    </script
```

What I'm trying to do here is to validate the form elements based on their types, for the javascript code, this is already included into a for loop that goes through all questions. I don't know the right syntax of checking whether a form element is a select or not based on the name attribute. qNum at my case is a variable that takes values such as q1, q2,.....
The alert(nominatefriend) never gets executed

Comment: You have duplicated `ids` in the page.

**ID is supposed to be unique in the HTML page**

Comment: @Sushanth-- thanks for your note, I got rid of the duplicated IDs and modified my code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct syntax is:

```
$('[name="' + qNum + '"]').is('select')
```

without the `:`

Comment: it should be `$('[name="' + qNum + '"]"').is('select')`

Comment: Good pick up @Arun, actually there is more wrong with this code, as it is not being triggered on form submit. The form submit will need to be added.

Comment: I tried this too, however, I get an Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name="q2"]"

Comment: Where are you getting qNum from ?

Comment: @AhmedEbaid there was another typo `$('[name="' + qNum + '"]').is('select')`

Comment: @JanR, actually there is more code that I didn't include in my post

Comment: @ArunPJohny, thanks for your comment. It should be $('[name="' + qNum + '"]').is('select')

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in various ways,

```
var element = $('#'+qNum);
```

You can do it using jQuery:

```
if (element.is('input')) {
    // do this
} else if (element.is('select')) {
    // do this
}
```

### OR

```
if (element.tagName == "INPUT") {
    // do this
} else if (element.tagName == "SELECT") {
    // do this
}
```

### OR

```
  if(element.prop('type') == 'select-one' ) { 
     // do this
  }
```

Comment: is this always true even when qNum holds is a changing variable.